# Уточнить перевод по тревогам

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки, тревоги

Есть такой знак как «[Прокурор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal)». В нём сказано следующее:

> Отметить 500 сообщений полезными тревогами

В оригинале это:

> Raise 500 helpful flags

То есть 500 **любых** тревог, признанных полезными, а не только на сообщениях. В частности, комментарии тоже подходят.

Для исключения разночтений надо бы подправить перевод, но для начала нужно определиться как он будет звучать. Пожалуйста, предлагайте ваши варианты в ответах или голосуйте за существующие.

Comment: Но комментарий - это тоже сообщение, как и вопросы с ответами.

Comment: @Suvitruf нет. Комментарий не является сообщением в интерпретации SE. Сообщение - это либо вопрос, либо ответ.

Comment: Я что-то не могу одно общее слово придумать. Видится мне, либо вообще избежать нужно слов типо **сообщения**, или же делать перечисление типо "500 полезных тревог на вопросах/ответах/комментариях".

Comment: @älёxölüt Мне кажется, что вы путаете "пост" с "сообщением". Именно "пост" является либо вопросом, либо ответом, но не комментарием.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov на руСО нет постов, и "post", и "message" - это сообщение.

Comment: Как по мне, то тут менять ничего не надо, большинству пользователей понятно, а что не понятно, как правило на Мета или в чате  уточняют...

Comment: @VladSpirin если можно сделать так, чтоб было понятно всем, то почему бы не сделать?

Comment: @Suvitruf тоже правильная мысль :)

Comment: @älёxölüt добавил предложения по знакам https://ru.traducir.win/string/3790 и https://ru.traducir.win/string/7856

Comment: @Suvitruf утвердил. Ждём подгрузки :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Еще один вариант,

> Оставить 500 полезных тревог.

Comment: Оставь тревоги всяк сюда входящий

Answer (score 2):

Вариация ответа Николая:

> Поставить 500 полезных тревог

Всё таки, мне кажется, тревоги ставят, а не оставляют.

Comment: Можно ещё **употребить** )

Comment: @Suvitruf ну, за флаги!

Answer (score 1):

Использовать 500 тревог, признанных полезными.

Comment: Использовать... Как я сам не догадался. Плюсую.

Answer (score -2):

> Отметить 500 **нарушений** полезными тревогами

Comment: Подтверждённые тревоги - это не обязательно **нарушения**. Например, комментарии, содержащие некоторые ключевые слова удаляются автоматически при первой тревоге. Но наличие ключевых слов в комментарии ещё не показатель нарушения.

Answer (score -4):

Обозначить 500 срабатываний справедливыми.

Comment: Нет, "справедливыми" (а точнее, полезными) тревоги признают модераторы (точнее, не только), а тут их надо именно использовать.